# In Windows8 Metro, how can I change the highlight color of the already selected item in a dropdown list

Tags: css, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I'm building a page in Windows Metro with WinJS. I have a DatePicker JavaScript object which is a basic select/option dropdown in the HTML. I have figured out how to CSS every part of it except for the highlight color of the selected item once you click on the dropdown. Whatever css class or pseudo-element I target, I can't get at that element. It always remains the default Windows 8 purple.

http://paulkarpenko.com/images/dropdowncolor.png

Let's say the dropdown is .myDropdown. 
I have tried

```
.myDropdown select        //styles pre-clicked select element
.myDropdown::-ms-value    //styles pre-clicked select label area
.myDropdown::-ms-expand   //styles pre-clicked select down arrow
.myDropdown option        //styles entire dropdown area
.myDropdown option:hover  //styles dropdown area's mouse-hover elements
```

Please help. How do I style that selected element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this - the colors should be garish enough to notice where they come from.

```
.myDropdown option:checked, .myDropdown:focus::-ms-value {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: yellow;
}

.myDropdown option:checked:hover, .myDropdown:focus option:checked:hover {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

Comment: YES! Thank you so much! option:checked; is what I needed.

Comment: .myDropdown:focus option:checked:hover is very important if you want to do away with ALL of the goofy purple!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the ThemeRoller Sample at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Theme-roller-sample-64b679f2 to help generate CSS to override all the controls.